# Lockout feature for every tenant .Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm developing **.NET Core** multi-tenancy app + **.NET Core Identity** with **lockout** feature. And I want to do **lockout** feature (I mean **max failed login attempts**) configurable for every tenant.

Now I do that for the all users in `Startup.cs` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    });

    ...
}
```

Can I do that setting configurable for every tenant? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a configurable property for each tenant you can use.

However, you can add this logic to the Login method of AccountController.

```
var result = await _signInService.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

If result is not successful, you can get the user via `FindByEmailAsync(model.email)` to check his failed attempt count

If its lockout count (which you can add as ApplicationUser property, Claim, Or some other method you prefer) is equal or higher then the limit you set for this user, you can lock him out.

This is probably the most basic way of checking this.

I would suggest that you implement a user service on top of the UserManager which will hold such logic, to ensure that this check will be performed on each PasswordSignInAsync() regardless of where it is used.

Comment: Then should I set for example `MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 100` in `Startup.cs` to use custom logic?

Comment: I would say that you need to remove the limit from Startup.cs if you want to define it per user.

Comment: By default this value = 5 and I need to do that over than 5. I think it will add potential issues for me.

Comment: By default Automatic lockouts are not enabled in .Net Core as far as I know.